# SQLite3 database per customer

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, rest, database-design

**Scenario:**

Building a commercial app consisting in an RESTful backend with symfony2 and a frontend in AngularJS

- This app will never be used by many customers (if I get to sell 100 that would be fantastic. Hopefully much more, but in any case will be massive)
- I want to have a multi tenant structure for the database with one schema per customer (they store sensitive information for their customers)
- I'm aware of problem when updating schemas but I will have to live with it.
- Today I have a MySQL demo database that I will clone each time a new customer purchase the app.
- There is no relationship between my customers, so I don't need to communicate with multiple shards for any query
- For one customer, they can be using the app from several devices at the time, but there won't be massive write operations in the db

**My question**

Trying to set some functional tests for the backend API I read about having a dedicated sqlite database for loading testing data, which seems to be good idea.

However I wonder if it's also a good idea to switch from MySQL to SQLite3 database as my main database support for the application, and if it's a common practice to have one dedicated SQLite3 database PER CLIENT. I've never used SQLite and I have no idea if the process of updating a schema and replicate the changes in all the databases is done in the same way as for other RDBMS

Is this a correct scenario for SQLite?
Any suggestion (aka tutorial) in how to achieve this?

Comment: If your functional tests show that MySQL works, why would you want to switch to SQLite?  You can have a dedicated database in MySQL as well -- and that seems like a good idea for guaranteeing separation of customer data (you can even put them on separate servers).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't have any functional test yet. I think about SQLite3 because almost all the info I find regarding functional test for my controllers talk about SQLite and I think it would be nice to have the same system for everything. I don't know SQLite but looks easier to backup as it would be only a matter of copying files. I just want to know if it's a simple approach and common practice... thanks!

Comment: This will be a maintenance nightmare and restrict your ability to do queries across multiple tenants. You're also segregating the database by tenant when it might make sense to know things by, for example, living unit. The rationale here appears to be security, but there are ways to build databases securely without having one per customer (it's done all the time), and database segregation is no guarantee of data security (an attacker can gain access to the application that can see them all or the filesystem they're on). Perhaps you should back up and ask a question about your security issues.

Comment: @Schwern I mean one **schema** per customer to be clear. Is not also security but also maintenance. Update schemas separately not affecting all my customers for example. I'm in the middle here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

Comment: @luso That's what I'd assumed. It's still a nightmare. Why do you want to isolate schema updates in something as simple as a tenant database? Do you anticipate this need a lot? More than wanting to update all schemas? Why? How will the app know which version of the schema each tenant is using, does it have to maintain queries for all possible versions, or will you be distributing different apps to each tenant?

Comment: @luso That article is 10 years old and is all about *performance* scaling, but that's not going to be a problem until you get into tens of thousands of tenants which makes maintaining tens of thousands of schemas even worse. If you have that problem there's far better ways to do it now than separate schemas. For example, the "name-value pairs" pattern can be better done with [Postgres JSON columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html). If you really want schema flexibility you could use a [NoSQL database](http://nosql-database.org/).

Comment: An interesting place this question arises for me is deploying a multi-tenant application on AWS.  Since sqlite is a single file database it is appealing to be able to store customer data as files in S3 and only have the most recently used ones deployed to disk at any point in time.  This also makes it rather trivial to cleanly support desktop and mobile app database that contain only and all of the user data.   

There is an appealing cleanliness to this in cases where it is workable.   Why have all the user data in an active db when most users aren't active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [I wonder] if it's a common practice to have one dedicated SQLite3 database PER CLIENT

Only if the database is deployed along with the application, like on a phone. Otherwise I've never heard of such a thing.

> I've never used SQLite and I have no idea if the process of updating a schema and replicate the changes in all the databases is done in the same way as for other RDBMS

SQLite is a SQL database and responds to `ALTER TABLE` and the like. As for updating all the schemas, you'll have to re-run the update for all schemas.

Schema synching is usually handled by an outside utility, usually your ORM will have something. Some are server agnostic, some only support specific servers.  There are also dedicated database change management tools such as [Sqitch](http://sqitch.org/).

> However I wonder if it's also a good idea to switch from MySQL to SQLite3 database as my main database support for the application, and

SQLite's main advantage is not requiring you to install and run a server. That makes sense for quick projects or where you have to deploy the database, like a phone app. For server based application there's no problem having a database server. SQLite's very restricted set of SQL features becomes a disadvantage. It will also likely run slower than a server database for anything but the simplest queries.

> Trying to set some functional tests for the backend API I read about having a dedicated sqlite database for loading testing data, which seems to be good idea.

Under no circumstances should you test with a different database than the production database. Databases do not all implement SQL the same, MySQL is particularly bad about this, and your tests will not reflect reality. Running a MySQL instance for testing is not much work.

---

This [separate schema thing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) claims three advantages...

- Extensibility (you can add fields whenever you like)
- Security (a query cannot accidentally show data for the wrong tenant)
- Parallel Scaling (you can potentially split each schema onto a different server)

What they're proposing is equivalent to having a separate, customized copy of the code for every tenant. You wouldn't do that, it's obviously a maintenance nightmare. Code at least has the advantage of version control systems with branching and merging. I know only of one database management tool that supports branching, [Sqitch](http://sqitch.org/).

Let's imagine you've made a custom change to tenant 5's schema. Now you have a general schema change you'd like to apply to all of them. What if the change to 5 conflicts with this? What if the change to 5 requires special data migration different from everybody else? Now let's imagine you've made custom changes to ten schemas. A hundred. A thousand? Nightmare.

Different schemas will require different queries. The application will have to know which schema each tenant is using, there will have to be some sort of schema version map you'll need to maintain. And every different possible query for every different possible schema will have to be maintained in the application code. Nightmare.

Yes, putting each tenant in a separate schema is more secure, but that only protects against writing bad queries or including a query builder (which is a bad idea anyway). There are better ways mitigate the problem such as the [view filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx#mlttntda_tvf) suggested in the docs. There are many other ways an attacker can access tenant data that this doesn't address: gain a database connection, gain access to the filesystem, sniff network traffic. I don't see the small security gain being worth the maintenance nightmare.

As for scaling, the article is ten years out of date. There are far, far better ways to achieve parallel scaling then to coarsely put schemas on different servers. There are entire databases dedicated to this idea. Fortunately, you don't need any of this! Scaling won't be a problem for you until you have tens of thousands to millions of tenants. The idea of front loading your design with a schema maintenance nightmare for a hypothetical big parallel scaling problem is putting the cart so far before the horse, it's already at the pub having a pint.

---

If you want to use a relational database I would recommend PostgreSQL.  It has a very rich SQL implementation, its fast and scales well, and it has something that renders this whole idea of separate schemas moot: a [built in JSON type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html). This can be used to implement the "extensibility" mentioned in the article. Each table can have a `meta` column using the `JSON` type that you can throw any extra data into you like. The application does not need special queries, the `meta` column is always there. PostgreSQL's JSON operators make working with the meta data very easy and efficient.

You could also look into a [NoSQL database](http://nosql-database.org/). There are plenty to choose from and many support custom schemas and parallel scaling. However, it's likely you will have to change your choice of framework to use one that supports NoSQL.